# Adding index for serach columns in Spring Data JPA & Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate and Spring Data JPA in my Spring Boot app and for database also use PostgreSQL. Generally try to add index to the most commonly searched columns. At the last time, I also use `@Lob` type column which has `TEXT` type in PostgreSQL.

Regarding to Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and Database side:

**1.** Should I add index to the columns that are used search filter parameter in app? For example, if I implement Specification for custom filter, then most of the fields can be used for filtering. Should I only used most used ones? (on the other hand, it is also disadvantage for create/update).

**2.** I use text search on PostgreSQL side in my `@Lob` column. So, should I add index for this column? If so, should I only add to Database via Flyway or also add on Entity using Hibernate annotation?

I am also wondering if I need to add all of the index / constraint / sequence objects to the entities via Hibernate annotations as well? Or is  it enough applying these objects to only via database script (e.g. Flyway) without adding any annotation to the Entity classes?

Comment: There are no general one solution fits all when it comes to performance. I'd suggest you look at every column and evaluate the use case behind that data to decide how it should be handled, and look at the usage patterns for the application. A query hitting one field may have you index it, but if that query is once a month and can sit and wait for the results, is it worth adding overhead to for an app with massive writing going on? Only metrics and monitoring can tell you. Lobs are generally NOT good for indexing, but again it depends on the index, data within it, and the index itself

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice explanations. "Lobs are generally NOT good for indexing" is also important for me to have a general idea. On the other hand, what about adding index, constraints or other elements to the Hibernate entity classes as well? Maybe it is not needed when we use migration script, but I am not sure if we should also add them to the Hibernate entity classes to show the related tables have these objects.

Comment: I should have elaborated on my statement: lobs don't usually lend themselves well to indexing because of the size and general use cases for them. DBAs would need to look at queries and plans to optimize indexing on these if required. As for annotations: its opinion based. I would only apply annotations where I needed the performance everywhere in every environment. My local dev environment though needs different DB setup and optimizations from the final production environment; indexing on the entities just gets in the DBAs way, and is usually wrong when assumed upfront anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding to adding dB objects e.g. index, constraint, etc. I will continue to add them when needed only database side via migration script. There is no need to use any annotation for them on Hibernate side as far as I understood. Just en exception, I think I should add sequence annotations to Hibernate entities. Right?

Comment: Yes - JPA has to know how to get the assigned ID value for managing identity, especially in relationships to set the Foreign keys. If you need a constraint set for the app to function, and might not use a script in a local dev environment, you might want it in the annotations so it is there if the DDL is generated from the entities. Otherwise, it is up to you on what works best. JPA just needs to know how to serialize your java objects to the database, so doesn't need to know about indexes (and to a lesser extent, constraints, even if they are pretty tied to joinColumn and not-null settings).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add index for all columns when our table size is getting larger. it's advisable to add after creating or along with table creation.

And one more when ever your using @Lob annotation to the column use @Transactional for fetching that column otherwise it leads to an runtime exception

Comment: Thanks for help, voted up. But I am not sure if we need to use index for every time our table size getting larger. Regarding to adding, should I also add annotation for Hibernate Entities besides adding via sql script?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are suggesting indexing all columns? Seems like advice that might not fit every situation, so might not be good advice. As for fetching lobs within transactions, again why? This seems driver/db specific, where some drivers (early oracle) require special lob handling and locators that might require being in a transaction to support. Hopefully not a requirement for Postgres's Text field, which is just a special varchar2 type under the covers.